# How do HDD's periodically refresh data?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, debian

I was reading/over-hearing some discussions which said that due to possibility of 'bit rot', hdd's periodically refresh data ? I have seen the hdd indicator giving a steady glow at times which means it's working.

If there is way that HDD's periodically refresh data, then it must be using some Operating System oversight ? If yes, are there any tunables that people can use/look into. I am using Debian GNU/Linux.

Update - From the comment it seems it ONLY *reads data* and not write data. If it does not write data, why it does that ? How does merely *reading data* prevent bit rot or/and hdd corruption ?

Comment: Hmm, periodic scrubbing _is_ a feature in some filesystems, as well as some RAID implementations – but generally it only _reads_ data; I haven't heard of any necessity to periodically rewrite it on a HDD.

Comment: I thought the idea/term of 'periodically refreshing data' meant it would read, if something is slightly broken, fix it. How does merely *reading data* fix things ?

Comment: That's exactly what a scrub does – it rewrites failed sectors with good data if it has another copy, or if the read succeeded after multiple retries. Actually the latter _is_ done by HDDs themselves, now that I think of it (unreadable sectors are marked as "pending reallocation")...